# How to set a user as RootDN in OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-14.04, ldap

I have installed `OpenLDAP` and `phpLDAPadmin` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.

I have a default `RootDN` which is something like:

- `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`

Then I have created some `users` and `groups` organizational units like that:

- `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`
- `ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`

I have also created a `Main Admin` user which will be the admin for all my services:

- `cn=Main Admin,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`

Now I would like to have the `Main Admin` as the `RootDN` (so, just one admin for all services included the LDAP service).

Is it possible to do that and how ? Just by changing the `olcRootDN` value ?

What's happened for the password ? Should I set the `olcRootPW` to be the same as the `Main Admin` password ?

Comment: You don't want to do this. You want to use the RootDN *only* for the server itself. Any action carried out by a human or an application should be done as a user registered in the DIT and having appropriate permissions. The reason is that the RootDN bypasses many checks internally, for example it completely bypasses the password policy overlay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently is it possible to do this just by changing the `olcRootDN`. The password which is taken into account is the `Main Admin` password.

To do this create a file called `rootdn.ldif` this way:

```
dn:  olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Main Admin,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
```

And run:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f ./rootdn.ldif
```

This way you can have something like that (*after deleting the `cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com`*):

- `dc=example,dc=com`

  - `ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`

    - `cn=service1_admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`
    - `cn=service1_users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`
    - `cn=service2_admins,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`
    - `cn=service2_users,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com`
    - ...
  - `ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`

    - `cn=Main Admin,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com` <- The new `olcRootDN`
    - `cn=User1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`
    - `cn=User2,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`
    - ...

Comment: I suggest to add SUDO before the ldapmodify, or you'll get 50 - Insufficient Access